# Rails: Trying to render a partial on button click

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, render, partial

I am trying to render a partial on button click but nothing happens. 
My view:

```
 <div class ="container">
   <span class ="center"><h1> Title</h1>
     <%= link_to "Correct Answer", correct_answer_courses_path, :remote => true %>
     <%= link_to "False Answer", false_answer_courses_path, :remote => true %>

     <div id = "result">
       <!-- This Div is used to render result -->
     </div>
   </span>
 </div>
 <%= render 'layouts/coursefooter' %>
```

My Controller (Courses_Controller)

```
def correct_answer
  respond_to do |format|               
    format.js
  end        
end 

def false_answer
  respond_to do |format|               
    format.js
  end        
end
```

correct_answer.js.erb (In Courses folder)

```
$("#result").prepend('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "correct") %>');
```

My partial is called _correct and is also located in the courses folder.
Right now when I click nothing happens, no errors at all.

Comment: try rename correct_answer.js  to correct_answer.js.erb

Comment: It was already renamed .js.erb (my bad made listed it wrong) but still doesnt work

Comment: try it like : $('#result').prepend("#{j render 'correct'}");

Comment: What are the contents of `_correct.html.erb`?

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli - that approach won't work inside erb.  It would have to instead be `$('#result').prepend('<%= j render(partial: 'correct') %>');`

Comment: Tried that still same result. My partial contains:



      <h2> Correct!</h2>
      <h3> Link to next question </h3>
       <%= link_to "Next Question", "courses_q1_courses_path", class: "btn-lg     btn-warning btn"%>

Comment: are you sure; no errors  at all? I guess you can see error in server log; or network tab in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will help...

Add a div with id `correct_answer` above result div and try to do this in the `js.erb` file like :

```
$("#correct_answer").html("<%= j render partial: "correct", :locals => {:questionnumber => @questionnumber} %>");
```

AND in controller set the variable like :

```
def correct_answer
  @questionnumber = 2
  respond_to do |format|               
    format.js
  end        
end
```

Comment: Also how would I pass in variables. I tried doing this
 <%= link_to "Correct Answer", correct_answer_courses_path, :remote => true, locals: {questionnumber: 2} %>

Comment: `locals: {questionnumber: 2}`  should be passed with partial render statement like: `$("#correct_answer").html("<%= j render partial: "correct", locals: {questionnumber: 2} %>");`

Comment: but then I would have to create a new file for each questionnumber?

Comment: I was trying to set a variable in the controller but I can't seem to get it to work

Comment: have you tried with global variable like `@questionnumber`

Comment: I put @questionnumber = 1 in the controller and <%=@questionnumber %>  in the partial but it doesnt work